# Making an array of structures?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I just made a struct that stored all the information about an employee together in one unit. Now I have to take all that information and put it in an array of structures called employees.

This is my struct:

```
struct EmployeeT
{
    char name[MAXSIZE];
    char title;
    double gross;
    double tax;
    double net;
};
```

Now how do I put that information into an array?

Thanks again guys

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. For C++ this is terrible code.

Comment: This is really basic C++. I recommend you pick up a [good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642).

Comment: In light of this and [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090098/how-to-define-a-struct-in-c), I really can't emphasize R. Martinho's comment enough. It's extraordinarily difficult to learn a language like C++ through a series of Stack Overflow questions. A good book is mandatory, lest you cement bad habits and develop fundamental misunderstandings early on in your programming career. Also, do be careful not to mix C and C++: they are emphatically *not* the same language.

Comment: I hope you're aware that `char name[MAXSIZE]` *is* an array... If not, you're now and the rest should be clear.

Comment: Go to the library or bookshop and get a book.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare an array of these structs like this:

```
EmployeeT myEmployees[/* ... size of array ... */];
```

Or, if this is pure C:

```
struct EmployeeT myEmployees[/* ... size of array ... */];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In C, you can create a fixed-size array of EmployeeT structs using this syntax:

```
struct EmployeeT employees[10];
```

The "struct EmployeeT" indicates the type of each element of the array, while the "[10]" indicates that it is an array of 10 elements. In C++, the "struct" keyword is optional and can be omitted:

```
EmployeeT employees[10];
```

You can then enter information into the array like this:

```
employees[2].tax = 2000.00;
```

This sets the tax of the 3rd employee in the array to 2000.00 (3rd because it's zero-based indexing).

Comment: Nitpick: Not static. Automatic. I know you mean the opposite of a dynamically allocated array, but it's not static. :)

Comment: @Xeo: I thought the same thing, but then found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/c-static-array-vs-dynamic-array).

Comment: @Xeo no one said array of static storage duration :P Static is way too overloaded a word.

Comment: @R. Martinho: It's one of my pet peeves, exactly because of that overloaded usage. :)

Comment: @Jesse: That question and most of the answers abuse the terminology to the point of actually being wrong.  Statically-sized arrays are not necessarily on the stack, if they have static storage duration they will go somewhere else (usually the data segment, but the standard doesn't say).

Comment: @Xeo: It might not be automatic, if it's global.  Or a class member.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks, I did feel the same way. Sometimes I wonder what people are thinking when they upvote an answer.

Comment: To avoid any issues I changed it to read "fixed-size." But I think referring to arrays whose sizes are fixed at compile-time as "static" is standard terminology. It doesn't imply anything about its storage class or lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n;
cout<<"Enter number of records: ";
cin>>n
employeeT *ptr_e=new employeeT[n]
```